# How to check Instagram username availability

Tags: api, delphi, instagram

how to check if the username is available or not in Instagram, i tried using Get request and catch 404 error, it dose not work sometimes, is there another way ?  a reliable one?

i tried using object pascal

```
 try
        lHTTP.Get('http://instagram.com/'+lPath, TStream(nil));
      except
        on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
        begin
          if E.ErrorCode = 404 then
          begin
            TThread.Synchronize(nil,
              procedure
              begin
                Form1.Memo2.Lines.Add(lPath);
                 Label2.Text:= IntTosTr(Memo2.Lines.Count);
              end
            );
          end;
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
```

but sometimes, when it returns 404 i go and check if user exist in instagram, but i cant find it and i cant register with the user, it says user is unavailable!

is there instagram api function that i can use it to check if user is available ? 
i realised that some accounts are closed! how to differentiate if its closed or taken or available ?

**UPDATE**

i think maybe this could be answer, but im not sure how to use it in delphi, [How do I check if a username is taken with parse.com when all User ACL:Public read/write is disable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34823496/how-do-i-check-if-a-username-is-taken-with-parse-com-when-all-user-aclpublic-re)

Comment: State what you've tried, and why it doesn't work (with code). The public API is the public API. Presumably you used the get by user id. Try the search api.

Comment: It is entirely impossible to explain why your code did not work when you do not include the code you used. *I tried, but I'm not going to show the code to you. Explain what I need to change* is not an acceptable question here. *it dose not work sometimes* is not a problem description that is useful (and *dose* is what is used for measuring medications). This site is for **specific questions** about **actual problems**, not *problems that happen sometimes with code I won't share with you*.

Comment: The answer is inactive accounts, and could easily be found with a google search.

Comment: dosent matter, is there another way ? @Dan

Comment: Why don't you try the API?

Comment: i tried, i tried searching for the username rn0 but didnt find a match !, `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=rn0access_tokenxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`  i guess its not reliable this way @smooty86

Comment: The HTTP API call shown in the comment contains errors. Try `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=rn0&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: Why oh why oh why won't you use the API?

Comment: This is a classic example of refusing to do things the right way and then wondering why it doesn't work as expected. If your car had a flat tire, would you replace it with a bike tire, or the spare tire in your trunk?

Comment: it will be great if you can tell us how to do it in the right way buddy, because this is my first time working with Instagram api @JerryDodge

Comment: Start by reading the documentation for their API. Then, look for the appropriate tools in Delphi which can work with that API.

Comment: i read it before, the search api dose not give you the exact username, it give you a list of users that match the username! @JerryDodge

Comment: @ColdZer0 yes, it appears the API uses partial matches... you can reduce your searches to 1 by uses the count parameter.  I don't think it's designed to do what you want to do, which is look for usernames that don't exist (possibly for the purpose of creating fake accounts)

Comment: No, its just an app to check available accounts, i think there is still a way cuz there is webistes  in the  internet for checking available usernames @JohnEasley

Comment: @ColdZer0 I found a question, and the answer says to search, then iterate the results to check for a match  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444427/check-if-a-user-is-banned-or-account-doesnt-actually-exist-instagram-c-sharp

Comment: but what about the banned and inactive accounts? this methode dose not work everytime @JohnEasley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very dirty. Complete the code on your own using these instructions

GET this url (to get cookies)

> https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_create_ajax/attempt/

POST to this url again

> https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_create_ajax/attempt/

with these values

- referer: https://www.instagram.com/
- new (custom) header named "x-csrftoken", value copy from cookie "csrftoken" which you received from GET

POST values

- email=... some random e-mail which does not exist on instagram ...
- password=... some strong password ...
- username=... your name ...
- first_name=... empty

You will get result like this if account can be created

> {... "status": "ok", "username_suggestions": ["..."], "account_created": false}

or this if not

> {..."status": "ok", "username_suggestions": ["..."], "errors": {"username": ["Sorry, that username is taken."]}, "account_created": false}

Answer (score 0):

Your API call example contains errors.

When I try

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=rn0&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

the server answers

```
{"meta": {"error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException", "code": 400, 
  "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."}}
```

As I do not have a access_token, I can't test more than this, but maybe it gets you started

Comment: because your are not supposed to share your access token online!, however the search api dose not give you the exact username, it give you a  list of users that matces the username!.