# How can i get instagram username availablity by using API in PHP or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, instagram-api

I have a textbox in my website where the user will type his/her Instagram username, What I want to do is when they type, At that time I want to call an API in the background that this username is available in Instagram or not.

I have created developer account in Instagram and get client_ id and tried with below API

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=merryshah568&client_id=01cc9370bd8e4adc9e6a2f4b3xxxxxxx`

but it returns

`{"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException", "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."}}`

I have also tried with this API

`https://www.instagram.com/merryshah568/?__a=1`

But it shows a blank page.

I am working on localhost.

Comment: I think the error message is pretty self-explanatory...? Are you providing any form of OAuth (bearer) token?

Comment: the id I am passing is Instagram client id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check Instagram username availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234274/how-to-check-instagram-username-availability)